# How to handle sample data creation/deletion in a managed package

Tags: managed-package

I'm providing a managed package with a tab for the subscriber to give the possibility (only if he wants, this is the reason because I did not provide sample data creation in a PostInstall Script)  to install  some sample data, in order to "test" the app feature. Now I know that if after installling the package and creation of sample data, if the subscriber wanted to uninstall the package, he would get errors related to the all package components referenced by the record created as sample data. Do you have any suggestions about the handling of this problem? For example, I'm thinking about another tab (or the same) to provide a button that automatically uninstalls all sample record created, in order to be able to uninstall the package, but I don't know if this is a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here mate! This is what you need :-)

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_uninstall_handler.htm

Comment: It's what I need! Even if I just got the solution -elsewhere- some minutes ago!